# Redirect non-www to www not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I set up a virtual server using virtualmin, it didn't create the .htaccess file so I created one in the public_html folder and put the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond % ^megahotserved.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.megahotserved.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

restarted apache and no effect and then tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName megahotserved.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.megahotserved.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

in the httpd.conf file, when I restarted apache firefox came up with an error

> The page isn't redirecting properly.
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct, you just need to follow the next paragraph which I quoted from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

> By default, mod_rewrite configuration settings from the main server context are not inherited by virtual hosts. To make the main server settings apply to virtual hosts, you must place the following directives in each  section:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteOptions Inherit
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have a VirtualHost that properly matches the `www.` address, so requests for `http://www.megahotserved.com/` are hitting the very same vhost and getting into a circular redirect. So the redirect is working fine; you just have a different part of the server config to fix.

Comment: `ServerName megahotserved.com
ServerAlias www.megahotserved.com
ServerAlias webmail.megahotserved.com
ServerAlias admin.megahotserved.com
<Directory /home/megahotserved/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +FollowSymLinks
allow from all
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /home/megahotserved/cgi-bin>
allow from all
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.megahotserved.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://megahotserved.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.megahotserved.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://megahotserved.com:10000/ [R]
`
Does this help ?

Comment: 'RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =megahotserved.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.megahotserved.com/$1  [L,R=301]'
works for me but it adds two slashes like megahotserved.com//index.php

how do I correct this ?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the above, and a small addition: it is better to redirect non-www to www rather than rewrite, otherwise you have two complete views ("copies") of your entire website; each page has two URLs, instead of one canonical one. This can be bad for search engines and other things.

Comment: no need to worry about that -- a RewriteRule with `[R]` generates a redirect :)

Comment: `ServerName megahotserved.com
ServerAlias www.megahotserved.com
ServerAlias webmail.megahotserved.com
ServerAlias admin.megahotserved.com
<Directory /home/megahotserved/public_html>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +FollowSymLinks
allow from all
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /home/megahotserved/cgi-bin>
allow from all
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =webmail.megahotserved.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://megahotserved.com:20000/ [R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =admin.megahotserved.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://megahotserved.com:10000/ [R]
`